# Get Auth0 user info in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, auth0, nestjs

I am trying to do Auth0 authorization in NestJS, but i am not sure how to get user's data on callback url handler.

At normal express function this could be solved by code below. I call passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) { }) function with callback function and receive user date in it.

```
// Perform the final stage of authentication and redirect to previously requested URL or '/user'
router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      const returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
      delete req.session.returnTo;
      res.redirect(returnTo || '/user');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

But i am not sure how this should be done in NestJS style. With decorators and guards. In NestJS i add next function. But how should i get user's data in it?

```
  @Get('cb')
  async callback(): Promise<any> {
    // WHAT SHOULD I CALL HERE?
  }
```

#### auth.controller.ts

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @Get('login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('auth0'))
  async login(): Promise<any> {
    const v = this.configService.get('TEST');
    return { r: 'ok1', v };
  }

  @Get('cb')
  // @UseGuards(AuthGuard('auth0'))
  async callback(): Promise<any> {
    // WHAT SHOULD I CALL HERE?
  }

}
```

#### auth0.strategy.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth0Strategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {
    super({
      domain: 'zzzz',
      clientID: 'zzzz',
      clientSecret: 'zzzz',
      callbackURL: '/auth/cb',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload) {
    console.log('Auth0Strategy payload', payload);
    return payload;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is [example](https://github.com/cdiaz/nestjs-auth0) on github how you can use Nest.js with Auth0.

If you check given example you can find that you need to do next things:

Define empty callback endpoint in `AuthController`:

```
@Get('/callback')
public callback() {}
```

Define middleware

```
@Injectable()
class Auth0CallbackMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  resolve() {
    return authenticate('auth0', {
      successRedirect: '/user',
      failureRedirect: '/'
    }, (req, res) => {
        if (!req.user) {
            throw new Error('user null');
        }
        res.redirect("/");
    }
    );
  }
}
```

Use that middleware:

```
@Module({
  providers: [Auth0Strategy, Auth0LoginMiddleware, Auth0CallbackMiddleware],
  controllers: [AppController]
})
export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer


.apply(Auth0LoginMiddleware)
  .forRoutes({path: '/login', method: RequestMethod.ALL})

  .apply(Auth0CallbackMiddleware)
  .forRoutes({path: '/callback', method: RequestMethod.ALL})

  .apply(EnsureLoggedIn)
  .forRoutes({path: '/user', method: RequestMethod.ALL});

  }
}
```

Check your validate function inside `Auth0Strategy`. In example it looks little bit different:

```
async (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
        return done(null, profile);
}
```